# Link plugin in tinyMCE

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, text-editor, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I have a text editor in my react app, i want to enable to insert a URL, but is there any way that I can only have the option in the toolbar and not when I right click ?
[image]

when I right click I dont wanna see that box, just wanna see the common options (copy,paste,print,reload)

This is my code

```
 <Editor
        initialValue={initialValue1}
        value={value}
        onEditorChange={(newValue, editor) => setValue(newValue)}
        initialValue="<p>Escribe...</p>"
        init={{
          height: 400,
          selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
          plugins: [
            
            'insertdatetime media table paste help wordcount lists image code link',
          ],
          toolbar: 
          '| media image link ' +
          'table tabledelete',
          language:'es'
       }}
   />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `contextmenu: false` to your init

Comment: What's the explanation for this? It didn't solve it on my end